Why In an electromagnetic wave both electric and magnetic waves are in sync and perpendeculare? if one makes the other shouldnt there be a delay?
Why are electric and magnetic waves in phase if one induces the other? Shouldn't there be a delay, similar to how potential energy converts to kinetic energy and vice versa? Additionally, why are their oscillations perpendicular? Is there an intuitive way to grasp these concepts without delving into mathematics?
when a particle moves there will be electric fields that are redirected and updated to the new position and the other that are still unupdated due to the delay of propagation of information which is the speed of light...so to prevent the discontinuity that will occur between the updated and unupdated parts. a region of the electric field will reorient itself despite the lack of information of the charge movement to serve as a bridge between the 2 parts i mentioned...but if it  tries to readjust itself and connect with the updated part with its current intensity...it will create electrical energy out of nowhere so to prevent  this violation of energy conservation, the electric field first lessens its own energy by converting some of it depending on the particle velocity in the perpendicular direction out of the plane since this perpendicularity insures that  this energy is stored and not lost in a way it doesn't interact with the plane**( and this becomes what we call magnetic energy )...and now the electric vectors can redistribute themselves at the same instance to account for the energy that is stored out of the plane so that the total electrical energy in the plane stays the same as before the particle even moved and that's why the redirection of energy in z direction (magnetic energy) and the readjusted part that makes the connection(induced electric field) happens at same time and by doing so it can provide the necessary adjustments to maintain continuity in the electric field

(in red are the updated vectors and in blue are the unupdated ones and in green is the electric part that insure the continuity)
untill the information of the new position of the charge reachs the unupdated part so it can orient itself in a proper way relative to the charge

What is the question? Also please use proper sentences.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no need for electric and magnetic fields to be in phase with each other. So your long question is just starting from incorrect premises.

Where did that figure come from?

At least in the near field of an antenna (and this is not just EM radiation, but actually an EM wave), the electric and magnetic field components are 90° out of phase. What are photons, EM radiation and EM waves

To answer to the question in the title and the first paragraph: consider the wave equation for the vector potential in the Lorenz gauge. E is its time derivative and B is its rotation, so E and B do indeed not generate or induce each other. You then also see that E and B are in phase for a running wave and out of phase for a standing wave.

Yes! you are correct, and the down votes are misguided. A changing E (B) field does not make a B (E) field.
See: Jefimenko's Eq.

Is the paragraph I wrote accurate? The perpendicularity ensures that some of the electric energy is stored without interacting with the plane. As the electric field in the plane lessened its energy, this will give it a ''cause'' to prompt redistribution at the very same instance to maintain the total electrical energy in the plane the same as it was befor the particul moovment (thus we get the syncronisation) ,and this redistribiution ensures continuity in the plane without violating energy laws

I don't know what that means. Fields don't make fields, they're made by charges and currents on the past light cone.

i see so when you said yes you are correct...what did you mean

@user402553 the part about fields not causing other fields. I didn't read the rest of the question a that point...too long.

than is it right to say that the lenght contraction can be interpreted as a rotation wich is also know as teller rotation and when this happen to the electric field ...an observer will precive this rotation effect and attribiute it to mgantic field?

no. Length contraction is about what you, at the origin, would learn from your invite lattice of clocks and rulers measuring the endpoints of a "rod" simultaneoulsy (measurements that are asynchronous in the rod's rest frame), while teller rotations is about what you observer receiving light signals at the origin as a relativistic object passes by.
